# why jQuery prev doesn't work in this case?

Tags: jquery

I  have group of section each has prev and next navigation buttons to navigate to the co-responding section.

```
<section id="sec1">
<img src="css/images/prev-btn.png" class="prev" />
<img src="css/images/next-btn.png" class="next" />
</section>
<div class="seperator"></div>
<section id="sec2">
    <img src="css/images/prev-btn.png" class="prev"/>
    <img src="css/images/next-btn.png" class="next" />
</section>
<div class="seperator"></div>
<section id="sec3">
<img src="css/images/prev-btn.png" class="prev"/>
<img src="css/images/next-btn.png" class="next" />
</section>
```

the next button is working just fine with the following code:

```
$('.next').click(function () {
    var next = $(this).parent().next();
    $.scrollTo(next, 1500, { easing: "easeInOutCirc" });

});
```

but the prev button does not navigate to the prev element.

i have tried:

This

```
$('.prev').click(function () {
    var prev= $(this).parent().prev();
    $.scrollTo(prev, 1500, { easing: "easeInOutCirc" });
});
```

and

```
$('.prev').click(function () {
    var prev= $(this).parent().prevAll().last();
    $.scrollTo(prev, 1500, { easing: "easeInOutCirc" });

});
```

and

```
$('.prev').click(function () {
    var prev= $(this).parent().prev('section');
    $.scrollTo(prev, 1500, { easing: "easeInOutCirc" });

});
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: So are you failing to find the previous section (as you attempts to fix suggest) or is the call `scrollTo` not doing what you expecting?

Comment: failing to find the previous section (alerting it says it is undefined)

Comment: The very first sample works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/pZepF/ . Aside from when you clicking on the prev button in the first section (for obvious reason). That said  jQuery object doesn't have `scrollTo` method.

Comment: `scrollTo` is a method from the jQuery ScrollTo plugin

Comment: liho1eye - not really... i have added id to each section. now if you do this:         var prev = $(this).parent().prev().attr('id');
console.log(prev); you will get undefined.

Comment: Still works as expected http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/pZepF/1/. Or you mean you get `undefined` when clicking on the first prev button? Well, of course - there is no prev for it.

Comment: What does `console.log($(this).parent());` show?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: rcdmk - 1.7,  liho1eye -  i forgot to mention that i have a div between every section (i have edited the code). maybe that is the problem?

Comment: that would definitely be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for you

```
var prev = $(this).parent().prevAll("section").attr("id");
```

Note that `prevAll()` appears to return elements ordered by distance from `this`, so the closest one will be first. And since `attr()` returns attribute for the first matching element, there is no need to call `first()` or `last()` on it. Magic simply happens.